# sed lines in script - exercise

Tags: linux, shell, sed

a simple question please

i have this code, and it add the word echo for all lines, but i want exclusively to odd lines

i kwow that this code sed -n 1~2p' show me all odd lines, but i can't doing the same in script above

```
sed 's/.*/echo &/' $startdirectory
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a literal answer to what you're asking (apply an 's' action to every other line), you want

```
sed -e '1~2s/.*/echo &/'
```

This is marginally better than the `N` way of doing things in that it doesn't interfere with other things you might want to do to other lines in the file.

Comment: wow, great help, it is exact i pretend: sed -e '1~2s/.*/echo &/;1~3s/.*/ecosystem &/'  - thanks a lot

Comment: Be aware that `~` is a GNU extension.  Since you're on Linux, that isn't an immediate problem, but it won't work where you are not using GNU Sed, though.

Answer (score 1):

Actually rather simple:

```
sed -e 'N;s/^/echo /'
```

The N reads a second line into the pattern space; the substitute puts 'echo' in front of the first, the implicit print prints both lines and empties the pattern space.

Note that if you have an odd number of lines, it drops the last.  Fixing that is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Fel: what do you think would do that job?  You are allowed to learn from answers given, and trivial variations on the previous answer should come automatically.